# How to save (forever) a file in android, and restore the data later?

Tags: android

I literally looked through stackoverflow trying to find the right answer... maybe I am doing something wrong.
I am making my first more elaborate app, that is quizz app for children. I want the scores to be saved in the highscorestable.txt, that will be later opened, updated, read, etc. The file should exist after closing the application to reuse it with the next game and so on.
I was using http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html . I want the file to be saved on the phone memory.
I have the following code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_high_scores);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String userData;
        scores =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.scores);

        if(intent.getStringExtra(EndScreen.EXTRA_MESSAGE)!=null)
        {
         userData = intent.getStringExtra(EndScreen.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        }
        else
        {
         userData="";
         }

        String temp = "";//to widzi przy zaladowaniu
        String output = "";
        String g="";

        //FIRST READING not necessary?
try{
            FileInputStream fin = openFileInput("highscorestable.txt");

            int c;
            while( (c = fin.read()) != -1){
               temp = temp + Character.toString((char)c);
            }
            fin.close();

        }
     catch (Exception e) {
            // e.printStackTrace();
     }   
        if(temp.equals(null))
        {
            temp = "";
        }

        //output = userData; //+ temp;
        FileOutputStream fos;//WRITING
        try {
            fos = openFileOutput("highscorestable.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            fos.write(userData.getBytes());
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        //READING2
        try{
            FileInputStream fin = openFileInput("highscorestable.txt");

            int c;
            while( (c = fin.read()) != -1){
               g = g + Character.toString((char)c);
            }
            fin.close();

            output= output+g;
            scores.setText(output);
        }
         catch (Exception e) {
         }
```

The intent itself works, actually everything works, however the fileitself does not last. I mean, when I start a new game, the old data is not restored. How to fix it?

Comment: Can you verify your assumption by running your app on an emulator and then exploring the storage with DDMS's File browser? Is the file being created and is it there at the time you start the app for the second time? If it is then probably you have a mistake in the logic of restoring the data.

Comment: OutputStream out = null;
   try {
     out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("highscorestable.txt"));
}  catch (Exception e) {
     }


have you tried BufferedOutputStream , because it allows you to append the existing file .i thinkn fileoutputstream only writes data not appending it,therefore your previous data is not exists.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I will try with outputstream like it is done here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818406/append-data-in-existing-file-in-android-and-read-it . -- > CHECKED, its not working either. Jawad Zeb, what do you exactly mean? @Egor - DDMS -  I have to look it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using sharedPrefrences: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

They are stored permanently in the app as XML and are only readable to the app if configured properly. (unless you NEED text, read here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html . **Remember to add the permissions to your manifest**)

**EDIT**:
try *appending* to the file not writing

Comment: I ve changed it to  try {
   fos = openFileOutput("highscorestable", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
   //fos.write(userData.getBytes());
   //fos.close();
   OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(fos);
         out.append("justSomeStringToCheck");
         out.close();